# Problema al poner admob en android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

He creado una aplicación en android studio y funciona bien pero al meter el tema de anuncios con admob ya no se puede ni abrir sale todo el rato la aplicación ha dejado de funcionar.
He seguido guias, tuoriales, etc.

He creado un proyecto nuevo en android studio con la activity admob seleccionando anuncio en banner paa probar sin meter nada de codigo si funciona y sale el mismo error, aqui os dejo el codigo:

**TODO ACTUALIZADO**

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
        android:value="true"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity> <!-- Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

MainActivity.java
    package com.example.ruben.safewin;

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
EditText editText4, editText5, editText6;
Button button;
TextView textView4;
private AdView mAdView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MobileAds.initialize(this, getResources().getString(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id));

    // Load an ad into the AdMob banner view.
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            //Use your own Test Device Id, from LogCat :  Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("xxxxxxxxxxxx") to get test ads on this device.
            .addTestDevice("821F6B84B97F82FBEBE855AD542340A4")
            .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    // Toasts the test ad message on the screen. Remove this after defining your own ad unit ID.
    //Toast.makeText(this, TOAST_TEXT, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    editText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    editText5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    editText6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}


public void onClick(View v) {
    float num1, num2, porcentaje = 0;
    float stake, stake1, stake2 = 0;
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialogo.setMessage("Los campos no pueden estar vacíos");
    dialogo.setTitle("Error");
    dialogo.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog=dialogo.create();

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(button.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

strings.xml

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">SafeWin</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<!-- -
    This is an ad unit ID for a banner test ad. Replace with your own banner ad unit id.
    For more information, see https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3052638
<!- -->
<string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3748175831230810/7065359892</string>
```

Esto es todo, no se si a lo mejor falta algo al copiar y pegar, espero una respuesta, gracias.

Aqui os dejo el logcat:

2018-10-20 11:24:59.561 1510-2134/? E/ANDR-PERF-JNI: com_qualcomm_qtiperformance_native_perf_io_prefetch_start

2018-10-20 11:24:59.562 563-3291/? E/msm8916_platform: platform_check_backends_match: Invalid snd_device =

2018-10-20 11:24:59.562 563-3291/? E/audio_hw_primary: start_dsm_feedback_process: pcm device id 43

2018-10-20 11:24:59.564 1510-2134/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityStartTrigger: not whiteListedcom.example.ruben.safewin/com.example.ruben.safewin.MainActivity/1

2018-10-20 11:24:59.566 1510-2134/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedcom.example.ruben.safewin/com.example.ruben.safewin.MainActivity/1

2018-10-20 11:24:59.571 1510-2134/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedcom.example.ruben.safewin/com.example.ruben.safewin.MainActivity/1

2018-10-20 11:24:59.581 563-3291/? E/msm8916_platform: platform_get_snd_device_backend_index: no hw_interface set for device speaker

2018-10-20 11:24:59.581 563-3291/? E/audio_hw_utils: send_app_type_cfg_for_device: Couldn't get the backend index for snd device speaker ret=-22

2018-10-20 11:25:00.649 27391-27419/com.example.ruben.safewin E/cr_VariationsUtils: Failed reading seed file "/data/user/0/com.example.ruben.safewin/app_webview/variations_seed_new": /data/user/0/com.example.ruben.safewin/app_webview/variations_seed_new (No such file or directory)

2018-10-20 11:25:00.690 27423-27423/? E//system/bin/webview_zygote32: Failed to make and chown /acct/uid_99524: Permission denied

2018-10-20 11:25:00.690 27423-27423/? E/Zygote: createProcessGroup(99524, 0) failed: Permission denied

2018-10-20 11:25:00.760 27453-27453/? E/asset: setgid: Operation not permitted

2018-10-20 11:25:01.228 1510-1630/? E/ANDR-PERF-JNI: com_qualcomm_qtiperformance_native_perf_io_prefetch_start

2018-10-20 11:25:23.934 1510-1600/? E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for bluetooth

Comment: Es importante agregar que se muestra en el LogCat, de hecho si es algo relacionado a AdMob en realidad ahí se despliega la razón del problema, busca donde muestre el mensaje "Caused by". Revisa [ask] y el [tour] del sitio, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Comentas que tu anuncio se mostraba, así que supongo que tu `ad unit ID` es valido, pero no veo necesario de un ["request Agent"](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest.Builder.html#setRequestAgent(java.lang.String)) para identificar el origen de tu petición, elimina la definición de este ["request Agent"](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest.Builder.html#setRequestAgent(java.lang.String)) :

```
// Load an ad into the AdMob banner view.
 AdView adView= (AdView) getView().findViewById(R.id.adView);
 //AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
 AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                   .addTestDevice("<id desplegado en LogCat>")
                   .build();
 adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Actualmente cambio un poco la [**inicialización de anuncios AdMob**](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#initialize_mobileads), por lo tanto debes usar `MobileAds.initialize( )` y revisa el `LogCat` para que obtengas el id del dispositivo de prueba que se requiere para definir en el método `.addTestDevice()`, este id se mostraría un mensaje en el `LogCat`, ejemplo:

> I/Ads: Use
>   AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx") to
>   get test ads on this device.

este sería un ejemplo del código completo:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Inicializacion
        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");


       // Load an ad into the AdMob banner view.
       AdView adView= (AdView) getView().findViewById(R.id.adView);
       AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                 .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                 .addTestDevice("<id desplegado en LogCat>")
                 .build();
      adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    }
    ...
}
```

Puedes preferentemente definir el valor del id de tu Ad unit dentro del archivo `strings.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    ...
    ...
    ...
   <string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx</string>
</resources>
```

obviamente puedes llamar tu `ADMOB_APP_ID` (ad unit id) desde `strings.xml` de esta forma:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, getResources().getString(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id));
```

Además es importante [**actualizar nuestro archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`**](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#update_your_androidmanifestxml) definiendo para la configuración de la aplicación la siguiente etiqueta  `<meta-data>`

```
   <application ....>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
            android:value="true"/>

   </application>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agrego un ejemplo con esta actualización:

https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android_AdMob

Comment: Antes de nada, gracias @Jorgesys por responder, he probado comentar esas lineas que me indicas pero nada, igualmente te adjunto el logcat por si es de ayuda. Te lo pongo arriba en la pregunta que aqui no cabe.

Comment: Vale creo que ye tengo solucionado el problema, en unos minutos os digo.

Comment: Ya se abre la aplicación pero ahora en vez del anuncio pone: Tests are being shown. To show live ads, replace the ad unit ID in res/values/strings.xml with you own ad unit ID.

Comment: @Ruben, debes definir el valor del id de tu Ad unit dentro del archivo strings.xml, revisa la actualización de la respuesta

Comment: tengo esto: `<resources>
    <string name="app_name">SafeWin</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <!-- -
        This is an ad unit ID for a banner test ad. Replace with your own banner ad unit id.
        For more information, see https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3052638
    <!- -->
    <string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3748175831230810/7065359892</string>
</resources>` Y gracias por el tiempo.

Comment: @Ruben he encontrado que ha cambiado la forma de cargar los anuncios, incluso ahora me he dado cuenta de este cambio,revisa mi actualización

Comment: Lo he intentado un poco @Jorgesys pero no me sale el anuncio, supongo que me habré saltado algo, mañana por la maña me vuelvo a poner. Gracias he visto que has hecho mucho trabajo.

Comment: @Ruben no te preocupes, no debes tener problema en mostrarlo,recuerda también revisar el LogCat para que definas el id del dispositivo de prueba, agregué esta info en la respuesta : .addTestDevice("<id desplegado en LogCat>") esto es lo que seguramente falta para que se muestre el anuncio.

Comment: He intentado un poco ahora @Jorgesys y no me muestra el anuncio, aunque ya no sale el mensaje que te dije antes, me sale en rojo el getview() de esta linea AdView adView= (AdView) getView().findViewById(R.id.adView); he intentado copiar del que tienes en github pero nada yo esque solo tengo un activity donde se hacen las operaciones de la app ya que son pocas. Arriba he actualizado lo que me sale en logcat.También te voy a actualizar como tengo ahora mismo mi app de verdad

Comment: Vale @Jorgesys creo que ya lo tengo, el problema es que pongo este de prueba de google <string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string> y funciona pero pongo el mio y no, no se si es que el mio solo funciona cuando este la app ya publicada o nose.